# Parse soap response and concatenate with another string

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy, soapui

I have been using soapui opensource for a small period and not yet good at groovy script. Please help figuring out the following issue:

I get response from the previous test step. Lets say **Response1** and need to parse it in order to get **Id** value from it. Then I need to add string **DomainId** before this id so that it looked smth like this:

**DomainId_234565**

and tranfer it to next request.
Could someone please explain how to do it with groovy? (I guess it is the best way to do it)
Thank you

Comment: Managed to resolve myself. Add property step **response** where I store response from previous step and also added property trasfer step to put response to the property.
Then I add groovy script:
`def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
    def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Properties#response")
    return "DomainId_ " + holder.getNodeValue("//*:Id")
  `
and it works, returns the correct value

Comment: add your solution as answer and mark it as solved. maybe it helps someone else...

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve myself. Add property step response where I store response from previous step and also added property trasfer step to put response to the property. Then I add groovy script: def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ) def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Properties#response") return "DomainId_ " + holder.getNodeValue("//*:Id") and it works, returns the correct value